# Is it possible to create TCP Private Network communication on WP8.1?

Tags: tcp, windows-phone-8.1

I want to make a simple TCP client using WP8.1 that can send some string to Windows 8 doesktop IN THE SAME LOCAL NETWORK. But when i see this documentation : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150599.aspx

they said " On Windows Phone, there is only one network capability (Internet (Client & Server))which enables all network access for the app. "

i've tried using WP8 to do such communication , and it worked well. I wonder if i could do the same thing with WP8.1.

does any body have a clue about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The page you link to will work between a phone and a desktop app on the same network.

The quote you pull out says that WP has just one capability to cover all network access rather than splitting different network access types into separate capabilities. It doesn't mean that the functionality behind the other capabilities doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks, i've tried myself and it works even using different library system.net.sockets and windows.netwoking.sockets